# Elisp Format specifier doesn't match argument type error

Tags: emacs, arguments, elisp, conditional-statements

I am getting a "Format specifier doesn't match argument type" error when trying to run my main function interactively. My code is:

```
(defun average(grade)
  (setq divide (/ grade 10))
  (cond ((= divide 10) "A")
        ((= divide 9) "A")
        ((= divide 8) "B")
        ((= divide 7) "C")
        ((= divide 6) "D")
        ("F")))

(defun main(g)
 (interactive "nGrade: ") 
 (message "%d" (average g )))
```

Can anyone help with what I am inputing/outputing wrong?
Thank you

Comment: Not related to the question, but Emacs Lisp does not have function scoping.  Your code binds `divide` **globally**.  Use a let binding for `divide` in the body of `average`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is in the format line

```
 (format "%d" (average g))
```

Wants to format an integer but you're returning a string, it should be:

```
 (format "%s" (average g))
```

As an aside, `M-x ielm` is useful when testing elisp.